# general javascript

Tags: javascript

i havent written in js in awhile and am a bit rusty apparently.  trying to understand the following problem.  the alert in `getCurrentPosition successCallback` shows the latitude correctly, but the last line alerts `undefined`.  why isnt my client_location function returning the latitude when call outside the function?

```
client_location = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      alert(position.coords.latitude);  ## RETURNS LATITUDE CORRECTLY ##
      return position.coords.latitude;
    });
  }
};
alert(client_location());               ## RETURNS UNDEFINED ##
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a callback to `getCurrentPosition` and your `alert` is inside that callback. Your `return position.coords.latitude` is also inside that callback. Your `client_location` function returns whatever `getCurrentPosition` returns and [`getCurrentPosition` doesn't return anything](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface).

If you want to do something with the latitude, you'll have to do it inside your callback; you could hand `client_location` a callback like this:

```
client_location = function(callback) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      callback(position.coords.latitude);
    });
  }
};

client_location(function(lat) {
    alert(lat);
});
```

Comment: +1 for the link to the `interface GeoLocation`.  Shows exactly why the final alerted value is `undefined` and not something arbitrary.

Comment: @Ray: I prefer to supply an authoritative reference rather than expect people to trust me as an authority.

Comment: hm.  im trying to write a simple function i can call that gets handed back the latitude, but i want to avoid having to pass any arguments to that function. how could i internalize passing in a callback into the client_location function?

Comment: @brewster: That's not going to work very well since `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous; so, you don't know when you'll get your result from `getCurrentPosition`. I suggest that you get used to the async callback approach, you have to deal with it all the time when using AJAX and a lot of other APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If the device does not return a geolocation it is undefined.
Add an else statement to deal with no geolocation.

```
client_location = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      alert("clientLocation: "+position.coords.latitude);
      return position.coords.latitude;
    });
  }else{
    return("no navigator.geolocation");  
  }
};
alert(client_location());
```